# Pygame: slow performance using pygame.Surface and convert_alpha()

Tags: python-2.7, pygame, pygame-surface

I'm developing a simple tile game that displays a grid image and paints it with successive layers of images. So I have-

```
list_of_image_tiles = { GRASS: pygame.image.load('/grass.png').convert_alpha(), TREES: pygame.image.load('/trees.png').convert_alpha(), etc}
```

Then later on I blit these-

```
DISPLAYSURF.blit(list_of_images[lists_of_stuff][TREES], (col*TILESIZE,row*TILESIZE))

DISPLAYSURF.blit(list_of_images[lists_of_stuff][GRASS], (col*TILESIZE,row*TILESIZE))
```

Note that for brevity I've not included a lot of code but it does basically work- except performance is painfully slow. If I comment out the DISPLAYSURF stuff performance leaps forward, so I think I need a better way to do the DISPLAYSURF stuff, or possibly the pygame.image.load bits (is convert_alpha() the best way, bearing in mind I need the layered-image approach?)

I read something called psycho might help, but not sure how to fit that in. Any ideas how to improve the performance most welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of things you can do.

1. Perform the "multi-layer" blit just once to a `surface` then just blit that `surface` every frame to the `DISPLAYSURF`.
2. Identify parts of the screen that need to be updated and use `screen.update(rectangle_list)` instead of `screen.flip()`.

---

Edit to add example of 1.
Note: you didn't give much of your code, so I just fit this with how I do it.

```
# build up the level surface once when you enter a level.
level = Surface((LEVEL_WIDTH * TILESIZE, LEVEL_HIGHT * TILESIZE))
for row in range(LEVEL_HIGHT):
    for col in range(LEVEL_WIDTH):
        level.blit(list_of_images[lists_of_stuff][TREES], (col * TILESIZE, row * TILESIZE))
        level.blit(list_of_images[lists_of_stuff][GRASS], (col * TILESIZE, row * TILESIZE))
```

then in main loop during draw part

```
# blit only the part of the level that should be on the screen
# view is a Rect describing what tiles should be viewable
disp = DISPLAYSURF..get_rect()
level_area = Rect((view.left * TILESIZE, view.top * TILESIZE), disp.size)
DISPLAYSURF.blit(level, disp, area = level_area)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, can you show me roughly what these two approaches might look like syntax wise in terms of my code?

Comment: added example of 1.  For number 2, it totally depends on how you know what to draw and often requires you to build your game returning update `Rect` so that you can build your list to pass to `screen.update()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I can use the example with what I've built so far, a great help.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `colorkey` whenever you dont need per pixel alpha. I just changed all `convert_alphas` in my code to simple convert and set color key for fully `opaque` parts of image. Performance increase TEN FOLD!